# How to submit value with function instead of inline onclick?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that works so far:

```
<a href="#" class="select_brand" onclick="$('#filter_brand').val('aerowatch');$('#filter_brand').selectmenu('refresh', true); $('#popup_brand').popup('close'); " class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Aerowatch</a>
```

Which I am trying to replace by:

```
// select element
$(".select_brand").on("mousedown", function(e){
    $('#filter_brand').val(e);
    $('#filter_brand').selectmenu('refresh', true); 
    $('#popup_brand').popup('close');
}
```

This seems to be semantically wrong. How can this be done?

Comment: It looks alright, though I wouldn't expect `.val(e)` to be what you want. Perhaps you want `.val( $(this).text() );`  (which would evaluate to "Aerowatch" in this case).

Comment: I am not sure to correctly understand your problem, but if you want to dynamically get the value of the clicked <a> element, you could try to replace `$('#filter_brand').val(e);` with `$('#filter_brand').val($(this).html());`

Comment: Stick `data-brand="aerowatch"` on the link, and grab it for your `val()` setter.

Comment: Almost there, something like this? <a href="#" data-brand="tag-heuer">Tag Heuer</a>  and then:  $('#filter_brand').val( $(this).text() );

Comment: $('#filter_brand').data('brand');

Comment: @delinear This does not work. I also tried: $('#filter_brand').val($(".select_brand").data('brand')); and also $('#filter_brand').val(this.data('brand'));

Comment: OK, got it! $('#filter_brand').val($(this).data('brand')); Thank you everybody.